# SQL Shuffle/Randomise database then order sample by column

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'm trying to achieve is to return a random sample of x size from a dataset, then order it based on a column. This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE integerField > 0
ORDER BY RAND(), integerField DESC
LIMIT 100
```

The idea here is that it will first order the table by random, effectively shuffling it, then order the first 100 rows returned by the integerField. I believe the problem is that it does not do the limit before the order, so I'm either going to get 100 random lines back or the first 100 lines of the database ordered by score (In this example, it's the former)

Is there a way to achieve this in a single query, or will the output have to be manually parsed through external logic/additional queries?

Comment: https://mitchwheat.com/2011/08/07/t-sql-generating-random-numbers-random-sampling-and-random-goodness/

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do ORDER BY rand and LIMIT in a subquery. Then order its result.

Comment: If you do: `SELECT RAND() FROM Table LIMIT 100` what do you see?

Comment: Add an order by to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55916955/87015. Does not guarantee the exact number of rows.

Comment: Needed sorting levels are independent. So you need a subquery - `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100 ) x ORDER BY integerField DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Utilise a substring to collect the initial randomised sample, then order it:

```
(SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE integerString >= 0 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100) 
ORDER BY integerField DESC
```

Credit to [Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina) and [jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh) for the pointer to use substring